# Download image from database to project folder (Paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to download an image stored in database with paperclip and put it in my project folder. In app/assets/images for example.

Do you now a way in order to do that ?

Comment: so why dont you store it directly in the folder rather than storing it in db and then fetching it from db to your folder,,,any reason for this :) ?

Comment: Because I want to put image in a Word. So when I use docx_replace or caracal gem I cant put directly image within the variable from database (that don't work). But I could put image directly from folder. So I want to put the image from DB to folder, put in the Word and delete it after insertion. That's why. But if you have another technique tell me ;)